# 50's style Ford Auto Gauges

Tags: resistance

I'm looking for resistance wire to re-wrap vintage auto gauges that have been burnt open. These gauges work by wrap wire around a metal bar that when heated it bends which moves the needle. The resistance wire needs to be insulated to be wrap around the bar. What came of the original gauge was 37guage /.005 wire the we are get 13ohms at 15". What kind of wire would you suggest to repair these gauges. Thanks for your help

Jack

Answer (score 2):

You can find nichrome resistance wire (example [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07K9M1RVD)). The 37 gauge is listed as 34.7 ohms per meter, which is reasonably close at 14.9 ohms for 15 inches. You may have to fine-tune the gauge calibration by adjusting the number of turns. If the gauge reads too high, you could also adjust by adding a small series resistor (a few ohms).

Although this particular wire isn't insulated, you could slip it into small-gauge (e.g. 0.5 mm ID) silicone tubing to provide insulation.

Comment: With the gauge working off heating the bar, would the silicone tube not hinder that? Also the tube needing to transfer the heat would it not melt?

Comment: @Jackw Yes, the silicone tubing will slow the heating effect some, but if the original wire was insulated it may not be that different. It can handle temps up to >400 deg C so it's unlikely to melt.

Comment: Enamelled Nichrome wire is available.